# Somando valores entre inputs html e javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Caros amigos, estou tentando adicionar soma entre inputs do html e do javascript, mas com esse exemplo, apenas consegui colocar no input do html. Como faço para implementar no input do javascript e somar o valor junto com o Valor Total?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No Html ta assim:

## html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function calcular(){
      var valor1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt1').value);
      var valor2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt2').value);
      document.getElementById('result').value = valor1 + valor2;
  }
```

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="titulo">Valor:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="0" id="txt1" name="responsavel" onfocus="calcular()" >
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="titulo">Valor Total:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="responsavel" id="result" readonly>
</div>
```

No javascript de onde eu adiciono outros dependentes esta assim:

## javascript

```
AddTableRow = function() {

    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";

    
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="usuarios['+ currentRow + '][nome]"></td>';

    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="usuarios['+ currentRow + '][cpf]"></td>';

    cols += '<td><select name="usuarios['+currentRow +'][cargo]">';
    cols += '<option value="gerente" name="usuarios['+currentRow +'][gerente]">Gerente</option>';
    cols += '<option value="Professor" name="usuarios['+currentRow +'][Professor]">Professor</option>';
    cols += '<option value="Programador" name="usuarios['+currentRow +'][Programador]">Programador</option>';
    cols += '</select></td>';

    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="usuarios['+currentRow +'][email]"></td>';

    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="usuarios['+currentRow +'][parentesco]"></td>';

    cols += '<td><input type="text" id="txt2 onblur="calcular()" name="usuarios['+currentRow +'][valor]"></td>';

    cols += '<td class="actions">';
    cols += '<button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button>';
    cols += '</td>';

    newRow.append(cols);

    $("#products-table").append(newRow);

    currentRow++;

    return false;
};
```

Comment: Podes adaptar o jsFiddle para o teu código com o problema que falta resolver? https://jsfiddle.net/L4sy0gk8/

Comment: Veja lá @Sergio https://jsfiddle.net/9zv3k4m3/2/# - Quando eu adiciono mais dependentes, o valor nao soma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes simplificar isso e clonar cada `tr`:

```
 var AddTableRow = function(el) {
     var tbody = $(el).closest('table').find('tbody'); // ir buscar o tbody
     var row = tbody.find('tr:last').clone(); // criar um clone
     var name = row.find('.calcular').attr('name'); // buscar o nome do clone
     var index = parseInt(name.match(/usuarios\[(\d+)\]\[valor\]/)[1], 10) + 1; // ler o numero (que é do original ainda)
     row.find('.calcular').attr('name', 'usuarios[' + index + '][valor]'); // dar novo numero ao clone
     tbody.append(row); // adicionar no HTML
 };
```

e agrupando no HTML esses inputs com uma classe poderia ficar assim:

```
function calcular() {
    var soma = $('.calcular').get().reduce(function(soma, el) {
        return (parseInt(el.value, 10) || 0) + soma;
    }, 0);
    document.getElementById('result').value = soma;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1fz9rx41/

Nota: juntei `thead` e `tbody` ao teu HTML que tinha tags em falta.

Comment: A pessoa não sabe brincar e responde com dois bloquinhos de código... Isso é roubo :p. +1 pela simplicidade

Comment: @Randrade é mais simples assim do que estar a escrever aquele HTML todo via JavaScript :P

Comment: Concordo. Além de ser mais simples, evita-se erros de digitação, como a falta de **aspas** no ID.

Answer (score 4):

A primeira coisa a ser feito é arrumar a sua função para adicionar linhas na tabela.

Ao observar a linha abaixo, podemos observar que você esqueceu das **aspas** ao colocar o **ID** do `input`. Com isso, o `onblur()` não funciona.

```
cols += '<td><input type="text" id="txt2 onblur="calcular()"name="usuarios['+currentRow +'][valor]"></td>';
```

Altere para iss:o `id="txt2" onblur="calcular()"`

```
cols += '<td><input type="text" id="txt2" onblur="calcular()" name="usuarios['+currentRow +'][valor]"></td>';
```

Após isso, basta alterar sua função `calcular()` para obter os valores de todos os `inputs`, e não apenas do **txt1** e **txt2**. Eu estou calculando os valores pela classe pois acho mais simples.

```
 function calcular() {
      var total = 0;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("valor");
      for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        total +=  parseFloat(x[i].value);
      }
      document.getElementById("result").value = total;
    }
```

Feito isso, sua soma deverá funcionar conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```js
var currentRow = 0;
var AddTableRow = function() {
  var newRow = $("<tr>");
  var cols = "";
  cols += '<td><input type="text" name="usuarios[' + currentRow + '][nome]"></td>';
  cols += '<td><input type="text" name="usuarios[' + currentRow + '][cpf]"></td>';
  cols += '<td><select name="usuarios[' + currentRow + '][cargo]">';
  cols += '<option value="gerente" name="usuarios[' + currentRow + '][gerente]">Gerente</option>';
  cols += '<option value="Professor" name="usuarios[' + currentRow + '][Professor]">Professor</option>';
  cols += '<option value="Programador" name="usuarios[' + currentRow + '][Programador]">Programador</option>';
  cols += '</select></td>';
  cols += '<td><input type="text" name="usuarios[' + currentRow + '][email]"></td>';
  cols += '<td><input type="text" name="usuarios[' + currentRow + '][parentesco]"></td>';
  cols += '<td><input type="text" id="txt2" onblur="calcular()" name="usuarios[' + currentRow + '][valor]" class="valor"></td>';
  cols += '<td class="actions">';
  cols += '<button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove()" type="button">Remover</button>';
  cols += '</td>';
  newRow.append(cols);
  $("#products-table").append(newRow);
  currentRow++;
  return false;
};



function calcular() {
  var total = 0;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("valor");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    total +=  parseFloat(x[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById("result").value = total;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="titulo">Valor Total:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="responsavel" id="result" readonly>
</div>


<br/>

<table id="products-table">
  <tr>
    <td>Nome</td>
    <td>CPF</td>
    <td>Cargo</td>
    <td>E-Mail</td>
    <td>Parentesco</td>
    <td>Valor</td>
    <td>Ações</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br/>

<button onclick="AddTableRow()">
  Adicionar Dependentes
</button>
```

Como está utilizando jQuery, pode alterar a sua função para isso, se achar mais simples:

```
 function calcular() {
         $('.valor').each(function() {
            total += parseFloat($(this).val());
          });
          $('#result').val(total);
    }
```